# image path is not identifiable on index.html of django3

Tags: html, django, model-view-controller, file-upload, django-forms

i am following a tutorial based on django 2 and currently running version 3 of django, the problem i am facing is the identifying path of the  tag on the front end of index.html, i'll post the code bellow , kindly tell me where i went wrong and any other mistakes

my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS= (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),) #static root added (A2)
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

my urls.py of main project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static 

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('posts.urls')),
    path('user/',include('user.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my models.py of app

```
class Posts(models.Model): #created this model field
    def min_len(val): #this is the custom validator working 
        if len(val)<=9:
            raise validators.ValidationError("%(val)s Must be more than 10", params={'val':val})

    title=models.CharField(validators=[min_len],max_length=255) #validation list provided
    content=models.TextField(validators=[min_len])
    
    thumb_nail=models.FileField(upload_to="posts/",null=True) #file field added 

class Posts_Form(forms.ModelForm): #to build a form using django and not html
    class Meta: #will get data of the fields=[] only
        model=Posts
        fields=['title','content','thumb_nail','user','category']
```

views.py

```
def index(request): 
    form=Posts_Form() #created form object
    data=Posts.objects.all() #retrive data from the model to display
    category=Category.objects.all() #we get all data of category 
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=Posts_Form(request.POST,request.FILES) #request.FILES for file data 
        if form.is_valid():
            # data=Posts(
            #     title=request.POST['title'],
            #     content=request.POST['content'],
            # )
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request,'index.html',{'title':'Add New Post','form':form,'rows':data,'categories':category})
```

and my index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content%}

{%for row in rows%}        
<h2>
            {{row.title}}
        </h2>
        <p>
            {{row.content}} - <small> {{row.created_at}}-{{row.user.username}} </small>
        </p>
        <p><img src="{%static 'row.thumb_nail.url' %}" alt="My image" width="150"> </p>
        <p>{{row.category.all|join:", "}} </p>
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

and my layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>
            {{title}}
        </title>
        <!--the below line is for the css bootstrap, from cdnjs official site-->
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"-->
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you referring to "row.thumb_nail.url" image not being retrieved ? Can you please clear this in detail? If yes are you able to see the "alt" attribute of image tag output ?

Comment: Yes exactly when retrieving it , it shows error for line 0 on the layout.htm

Comment: Yes I can se alt tag

Comment: <p><img src="{% if row.thumb_nail %}
                            {{ row.thumb_nail.url }}
                        {% else %}
                                #   
                        {% endif %}" alt="My image" width="150"> </p>